# ggplot: (manually) create legend when referencing different data.frames

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Ok, lets take some sample data.

```
A <- sample(1:100, 25)
B <- sample(1:25, 25)
df.1 <- data.frame(A,B)


C <- sample(1:80, 15)
D <- sample(1:15, 15)
df.2 <- data.frame(C,D)
```

Then we plot the data using `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)

(plot2 <- ggplot(NULL) + 
   geom_point(data=df.1, aes(x=A, y=B), 
              color='black', cex=1, pch=16 ) +
   geom_smooth(data=df.1, aes(x=A, y=B), method="lm", size=1, 
               se=FALSE, colour="black", linetype=2)+
   geom_point(data=df.2, aes(x=C, y=D), 
              color='black', cex=1, pch=15 ) +
   geom_smooth(data=df.2, aes(x=C, y=D), method="lm", size=1,  
               se=FALSE, colour="black", linetype=1)+
   scale_y_continuous("Y scale") +
   ggtitle("Plot") +
   theme_bw()+
   theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=20),
         axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.25),
         axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1),
         axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size=15)
   )
)
```

So we have created and modified the title, axis, etc.

But I want to create a legend which shows the `linetype`'s from the `geom_smooth()` function of `df.1` and `df.2`. It should be in the top right of the graph.

(so for `df.1` we want a solid line and `df.2` a dashed line)

The example [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/) walks you through an example, but the data comes from within the same data set

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need the two dataframes? Would it not be easier to first merge the data and then group by source?

Comment: lets say they are of differenet lengths and different variables name. But happy to see a solution if you can combine to one dataframe

Comment: Done. In hindsight, merge was the wrong word. I meant combine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#combine and create x and y (as mappings follow
#same pattern)
df.1$group <- "df.1"
df.1$x <- df.1$A
df.1$y <- df.1$B

df.2$group <- "df.2"
df.2$x <- df.2$C
df.2$y <- df.2$D

library(plyr) #for rbind.fill

df.all <- rbind.fill(df.1,df.2)

plot3 <- ggplot(df.all, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group)) + 
  geom_point(color='black', cex=1, pch=16 ) +
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype=group),method="lm", size=1, 
                         se=FALSE, colour="black") +
  scale_y_continuous("Y scale") +
  ggtitle("Plot") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=20),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.25),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1),
        axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size=15)
  ) +
#add custom linetypes (not necessary now, as default mapping to 1 and 2)
plot3 + scale_linetype_manual(values=c("df.1"=1,"df.2"=2))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, so when you have data.frames of variables length, its best to combine them and then plot. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Not necessarily, but when you're doing essentially the same with each dataframe (like you're doing here) it's better to combine with a column indicating which group a measurement belongs to. Then you can group by group indicator and assign aesthetics (using `aes(...)` which automatically generate the legend.